# Can we send data to json api while user is not using the app (in foreground)?

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-studio

Can we send data to JSON API while the user is not using the app (in the foreground)?
like the user has not opened the app and we can send data to JSON API in the foreground ??

plzz help , if we can do it then how?

Comment: You need to use a background service, it can perform network connections,like send or save data https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!I read your question I think you are implementing an online/offline scenario. In this scenario, in android, we are creating a class that extends to Application and also implements LifecycleObserver. This implement method two methods:

```
 @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
private void onAppForegrounded() {
//do something
}

 @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
private void onAppBackgrounded() {
//do something

}
```

and also add this line of code in your manifest file inside the application tag:

```
android:name=".YourClassName"
```

and also ad this line of code in your Gradle file inside the Dependencies body:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```